# Can I use pseudofields in anything other than source?

Tags: 9, migrations, configuration

If I use pseudofields in the source property for my custom plugin, they are correctly substituted with the computed values. If I use them in another configuration (as per the example), they are treated as literal strings:

```
 field_myfield:
    -
      plugin: my_custom_plugin
      items:
        -
          title: 'Title 1'
          content: '@computed_field_1'
        -
          title: 'Title 2'
          content: '@computed_field_2'
```

Is what I'm attempting actually possible?

Comment: You have to define the pseudo fields first in your migration file. Do you have a larger sample that shows them being defined? Look also at https://understanddrupal.com/lessons/using-constants-and-pseudofields-data-placeholders-drupal-migration-process-pipeline/